# Wordpress - Custom username color for specific role

Tags: wordpress, colors

Any Wordpress specialists here?

In fact that I couldn't find any plugin... I've got a question.  How can I add a custom color to specific user role? For example I need to add red color for administrator role, and green color for translator role. I want to display it on front of course (index page, comments etc... everywhere where user name appears).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a lot of different parts to this question.  Have you tried anything?

I'm unaware of a way to add a field to the user role but you could add it to specific users. As a starting point, I would add a custom meta field users where you could enter a hex value for a colour.  You could use a tool such as [CMB2](https://github.com/CMB2/) for this, which even provides a colour picker field.

From this point you could then access the colour specific to the user using [get_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) and apply this to certain elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try with CMB2. I use specific user role plugin as well.

Comment: Tooleset Types works for me as well. Thank you for clue!